# An error occurred while starting the karnel - Anaconda python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, anaconda

I installed Anaconda (Python 3.6) on Windows 10 64 bit home edition. I'm getting below error just after starting the Spider 3 from Anaconda Navigator:

Initially its showing **kernel died, restarting** and then below error:

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in 
>   main()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 220, in main
>   kernel.initialize()
>   File "", line 2, in initialize
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
>   return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
>   self.init_sockets()
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 236, in init_sockets
>   self.shell_socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 146, in socket
>   s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type, **kwargs)
>   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 285, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.**cinit** (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3861)
>   zmq.error.ZMQError: Permission denied

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed after this installation. In Windows 7 64 bit its working fine; however, why its showing problem in Windows 10? Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstalled everything, that has a word "python" in it. And, re-installed only Anaconda, restarted PC. Then error removed.